# FirebaseMessaging getInitialMessage keeps old behavior despite changing the code

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am testing how my Flutter app handles notification using my Samsung Android 12 phone and Firebase Messaging campaign.

I have gotten this code (simplified) to work for a month and notification is handled properly.

```
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) {
      if (message != null) {
        String? routeName = message.data["route"];

        if (routeName != null) {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(routeName);
        }
      }
    });
```

However, today when I wanted to change how handling notification works, I found out that the changes I made to this code are not reflected in the app when debugging through Flutter. Opening the app from a terminated state through the notification still behaves according to the old code above.

I have tried many things:

1. Uninstalling the app on Android
2. Removing all code related to Firebase Messaging
3. Clearing all app cache and data

But the app still keeps the behavior of the old code. Is there anything I can do to reset the behavior of `FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage()` ?